# Only show unique date values in ng-repeat list

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a unordered list generated by an ng-repeat. In each list item I have a month header and a blog post.

[image]

I only want to show one instance of each month name but I can't work out a nice way of doing this without some really hacky jQuery.

Is there a way I can somehow detect this value in Angular and use an ng-hide to only show the first one of each type?

Comment: Sounds like you could use some **[$filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)ing** in your `ng-repeat`, but without seeing some sample code it is difficult to propose anything more specific.

Comment: +1 for the impressively clear visual (how did you create it ?)

Comment: I'll look into filtering thanks. I'm a designer/developer so I used Sketch (because I had it open at the time). http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this could help, providing that your same-month posts are adjacent. If they are not, maybe it's okay to show the date altogether:

[plnkr code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/wUvHpdZ5FNItdwynHlkn?p=preview)

Basically:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in model.blogPosts">
    <span ng-show="model.blogPosts[$index - 1].date !== post.date">{{post.date}}</span>
    <br>
    <span>{{post.post}}</span>
</li>
```

Edit:

(Sorry for the default ul li styling, such uglyness)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably modify your data to achieve this. Turn your post list into an object like

```
$scope.postsByMonth = {
  October: [//...october posts],
  November: [//...november posts],
  //...
};
```

Then you can do something along these lines

```
  <li ng-repeat-start="month, posts in postsByMonth">month<p>posts[0]</p></li>
  <li ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="post in posts.slice(1)"><p>post</p>
```